# String to Date Parsing Java

Tags: java, date, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse UTC TimeZone in my Date, for this first i am formatting it with SimpleDateFormat and then i am passing "UTC" in formatter TimeZone. But the problem is that when i am trying to parse that string to Date, it again change the time without UTC format.

```
private Date getDateUTC_Converter(Date dateString) {

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        // dateString = Mon Feb 01 13:00:00 GMT+04:00 2016
        Date value = null;

        try {//  Mon Feb 01 13:00:00 GMT+04:00 2016
        // After UTC  Mon Feb 01 09:00:00 +0000 2016
            String abc = formatter.format(dateString);
            value = formatter.parse(abc);
       // After i am getting this   Mon Feb 01 13:00:00 GMT+04:00 2016 here.

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return value;
        }
```

Comment: For start, should dateString be a String object instead of a Date object?

Answer (score 0):

Don't format your input string. Parse it straight away.

```
private Date getDateUTC_Converter(String dateString) { 
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    try {
        // suppose dateString = "Mon Feb 01 13:00:00 GMT+04:00 2016"
        // this returns "Mon Feb 01 09:00:00 +0000 2016"
        return parser.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```